# What is tag "eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name" for?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

In [tutorial](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/160_advanced-networking/secondary_cidr/prerequisites/) of AWS EKS, for adding secondary CIDRs to the new VPC, We should add following tags to the new subnets

1. eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name
2. kubernetes.io/cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
3. kubernetes.io/role/elb

I know tag2 and tag3 are for discovery by load balancers or ingress from this [site](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-vpc-subnet-discovery/), but **What is tag1 "eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name" for?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this tag shows the cluster name.
The tag name is defined below:
https://github.com/eksctl-io/eksctl/blob/release-0.25/pkg/apis/eksctl.io/v1alpha5/types.go#L171-L172.

And for example, the defined constant is used by the function of getting a cluster name.
https://github.com/eksctl-io/eksctl/blob/release-0.25/pkg/cfn/manager/cluster.go#L189-L209

So maybe the eksctl judge a cluster name from an "eksctl.cluster.k8s.io/v1alpha1/cluster-name" tag.

Comment: and the rest of the answer is "... so kubernetes can tell which ELB, Subnets, and other cloud assets it should have control over, to avoid inspecting **every** ELB, Subnet, etc in order to keep them in sync"

Comment: Thank you for your addition. I'm not familiar about implement of eksctl because I started reading the code after see this question. It was very helpful!

Comment: It's actually not specific to EKS, that's why I said kubernetes. It's behavior of the cloud-provider subsystem in kubernetes

Comment: Oh really. I completely thought many cloud-provider subsystems in Kubernetes use the status field of Kubernetes resource(e.g. ingress controller, type: LoadBalancer, and CSI driver). I'm interested in other tools these kinds using cloud provider tag data without Kubernetes resources like eksctl.